# Ajax call sometimes Fails to find the file

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, nginx

I have a very simple AJAX login. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

For all that I can see as (as highlighted in red in the Chrome Dev Tools) it fails to find the file sometimes.  I dont know if this is problem with JQuery, latest PHP version or my NGINX. mainly because sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Any ideas on how could i fix this?

The following is the code used to login and the image is the Chrome Dev Tools

```
    var user = $("form.logIn").serialize();
    $.post("http://xxx.xx.xx.102/pageResources/phpLibraries/login.php", user, function(data) {

       if ( typeof data.ok !== "undefined" ) {
            window.location.replace("http://xxxx/index.php?id=27");
            }
   });
```

[image]

```
POST http://xxxxxx/pageResources/phpLibraries/login.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://xxxxxx/localhost
Origin: http://xxxxx
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

When I change the AJAX call to dont include the IP address then the header sent is

```
POST http://xxxxx/pageResources/phpLibraries/login.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://xxxxx/index.php?id=1
Origin: http://xxxxx
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: You should give more information and code, with this we can't help you.

Comment: Click on that `login.php` row that is highlighted red and see exactly what happened. Red doesn't necessarily mean it wasn't found, it could be a 505 server error.

Comment: @jszobody sorry I attached the wrong picture. There is nothing under response or preview for me to see an error. all I can see is that the file name is in red.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a crossdomain issue?

Comment: ^^ That. I think you're calling a different domain, which the browser won't allow. Change your `$.post` to a relative URL if it's the same domain. Or research CORS to see how to do cross-domain ajax.

Comment: There is no domain attached to that IP as of right now as is a dev environment. There is no cross domain call. it doesnt explain why it works and sometimes it doesnt

Comment: @JonathanThurft what does it say in the `Console` tab of developer tools?

Comment: @JonathanThurft So you can change the URL in your code to `/pageResources/phpLibraries/login.php` right? No `http://xxx.xx.xx.102/` needed?

Comment: @jszobody I did that. Still the same issue. sometimes it finds it sometimes it doesnt